Haskell HashTable from ST monad
I am trying to work with Haskell St monad, but, unfortunatly, do not understand, how to combine pure functions and this monad. Here are example of program that need to count individuals words in text, through of splitting to words and adding them to hashtable. Function count tries to build HashMap. There are neat (commented) solution for Map , that have fromListWith, but mutable HashTable from ST monad does not have this, but it has function mutate, that potentially can perform building hashmap. Unfortunately, i cannot achive more than performing single insert operaions
Exampe:
    (do{ht <- H.new;H.mutate ht "abcd" (\v->case v of {
    Nothing ->(Just 1,"abcd");
    Just x ->(Just(x+1),"abcd")});
    return ht}) 

does not work if performed inside foldl(r). After applying function to accumulator(hashtable) returns object in ST monad. Can i use standart looping functions with ST hashtable? Or there are some monadic operators that i am unaware?
    {-# LANGUAGE TupleSections #-}
    import Data.Char(toLower)
    import Data.Hashable(Hashable)
    --import Data.HashMap(Map, fromListWith)
    import Text.Regex.TDFA
    import Control.Monad.ST;import Data.STRef
    import qualified Data.HashTable.ST.Basic as H
    import qualified Data.HashTable.Class as C
    type HashTable s k v = H.HashTable s k v
    st = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor             incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat     non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. "
    re = "[a-z0-9]+"
    --count :: (Hashable a, Ord a) => [a] -> Map a Int
    {-count = Map.fromListWith (+) . map (,1)-}
    count ws =do{ht <- H.new;
    foldl (\ht w -> H.mutate ht w
    (\v -> case v of 
      {Nothing ->(Just 1,w);
       Just x ->(Just(x+1),w)}
    )
          ) ht ws;
     return ht}
    --main = putStr $ show $ count (getAllTextMatches((map toLower st) =~ re) :: [String])



The following definition of count ws should work:
count :: [String] -> [(String, Int)]
count ws = runST $ do
  ht <- H.new
  mapM_ (\w -> H.mutate ht w $ \v -> case v of
            Nothing -> (Just 1, ())
            Just x -> (Just (x+1), ())) ws
  C.toList ht

Note several things about this function:

In order to write count as a pure function with no ST in its type signature, it must use runST to actually execute the mutating do block, and it cannot return a hash table of type H.Hashtable s String Int, because this type can only "exist" within the ST monad.  That's why we need to convert the final result to a list at the end with C.toList ht.

The H.mutate function creates a monadic action.  Specifically, it has the type:
H.mutate ht w f :: ST s a

You can't fold this over the hash table ht because it doesn't return a hash table value.  To work with sequences of monadic actions like this, you need to use functions like sequence, mapM, foldM, and some of their variations, which you can find in Control.Monad.  In this case, you have a list of pure values ws :: [String] that you'd like to convert to a sequence of monadic actions that are executed in order, and mapM (or its variant mapM_) will work.
(Be warned that I'm talking about mapM_ from Control.Monad, not the function mapM_ that appears in Data.Hashtable.Class.  That hash table version serves a different purpose and would not be useful here.)

The "return value" of H.mutate that appears in the second half of the tuple (e.g., the w in (Just 1, w)) is only important if you want H.mutate to read information out of the hash table for use outside of the H.mutate operation itself.  Here, we only need to read information out  of the hash table within the H.mutate operation, to read and increment the counter, so this return value is not useful to us.  That's why we can just return the unit value ().


Here's a self-contained example demonstrating this version of count:
import Data.Char(toLower)
import Text.Regex.TDFA
import Control.Monad.ST
import qualified Data.HashTable.ST.Basic as H
import qualified Data.HashTable.Class as C

st :: String
st = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor \
     \incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud \
     \exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute \
     \irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla \
     \pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia \
     \deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."

re :: String
re = "[a-z0-9]+"

count :: [String] -> [(String, Int)]
count ws = runST $ do
  ht <- H.new
  mapM_ (\w -> H.mutate ht w $ \v -> case v of
            Nothing -> (Just 1, ())
            Just x -> (Just (x+1), ())) ws
  C.toList ht

main :: IO ()
main = putStrLn $ show $ count (getAllTextMatches (map toLower st =~ re))


Thanks!!! Now  I understand, that monadic and pure operations are separeted and i need to monadic  operators to looping and unboxing  values from monads. Haskell is so magnetic, but sometimes so difficult to make advance:)
